# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph' with Stocks Prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to use the same code in this [page](https://medium.com/@randerson112358/stock-price-prediction-using-python-machine-learning-e82a039ac2bb) but I am getting an error at the middle of the code.

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-9ff70788070d> in <module>()
----> 1 model = Sequential()
      2 model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1)))
      3 model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=False))
      4 model.add(Dense(units=25))
      5 model.add(Dense(units=1))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in get_uid(prefix)
     66     """
     67     global _GRAPH_UID_DICTS
---> 68     graph = tf.get_default_graph()
     69     if graph not in _GRAPH_UID_DICTS:
     70         _GRAPH_UID_DICTS[graph] = defaultdict(int)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'
```

Here is my import list:

```
    #Import the libraries
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, RepeatVector, Masking, TimeDistributed
from tensorflow. keras.utils import plot_model
import quandl
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import pandas_datareader as web

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import math
from keras.models import Sequential


from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
#import tensorflow as tf
#newinv=inventory+str(add)
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
python tensorflow machine-learning keras
```

---

**Update:** After editing the code based on Giorgos' answer, no I get this is the error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-9ff70788070d> in <module>()
----> 1 model = Sequential()
      2 model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1)))
      3 model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=False))
      4 model.add(Dense(units=25))
      5 model.add(Dense(units=1))

NameError: name 'Sequential' is not defined
```

Here is my import list:

```
       import math
import pandas_datareader as web
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import quandl
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
```

Here is where I am getting the error:

```
#Build the LSTM network model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1)))
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(units=25))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
```

Comment: It's probably a version issue - `get_default_graph` was removed from the base tensorflow module in TF2.0. Looks like it can still be imported with `tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph` (See the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/get_default_graph))

Comment: Re-reading your question, it looks like the issue is within Keras itself. I'd check the versions of both Keras and Tensorflow you have installed.

Comment: @BrendanA. I have added " tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph" but still same error.

Comment: @BrendanA. I am currently using https://colab.research.google.com/ would you please explain what to do to send the versions or install older TF

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `tf.keras`, instead of

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
```

use the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf


model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=False))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=25))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1))
```

---

And also make sure to remove your older import `from keras.models import Sequential` so that `Sequential()` is not overwritten in namespace. Same applies for `from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM`.

Comment: I changed it but now it says: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-9ff70788070d> in <module>()
----> 1 model = Sequential()
      2 model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1)))
      3 model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=False))
      4 model.add(Dense(units=25))
      5 model.add(Dense(units=1))

NameError: name 'Sequential' is not defined

Comment: @Abood I can see `model = Sequential()`. Your imports are pretty messy so I don't trust whether you have actually changed the import or not. If you want more help, update your imports in your question.

Comment: Yes I know, I am organizing it now.
here is it
#Build the LSTM network model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1)))
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(units=25))
model.add(Dense(units=1))

Comment: @Abood Edit your __question__ (this is a comment) and include both the imports and the code. I don't understand how you expect others to help you out when you don't share the code. Honestly I don't understand.

Comment: Okay done! I have edited the imports and included where I am getting the error

Comment: I think I didnt say I am an expert, I am still learning, if you want to help thank you, if not just leave it to others and will be thankful to them

Comment: Thank you for your help. i am still getting an error: ---> 11 model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1)))
 

AND TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <keras.layers.recurrent.LSTM object at 0x7f3baf11ba90>

Comment: @Abood Updated. Also make sure to remove `from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
`

Comment: Unfortunately, a new error: InvalidArgumentError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for 'lstm_2/strided_slice_2' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [0,?,1], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <0>, input[2] = <1>, input[3] = <1>.

Comment: @Abood Check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50385447/how-to-deal-with-keras-erroslice-index-0-of-dimension-0-out-of-bounds. If you still have issues, feel free to ask a different question. It is always better to stick to one problem at a time. I think the new error is out of the scope of this question. :)

Comment: I have tried the answer in the link but it doesnt work. Thank you so much for your time. I will as a different question as you said, thanks again

Comment: @Abood No worries. If you ask a different question share the link here and I'll try to answer.

Comment: Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61124969/slice-index-0-of-dimension-0-out-of-bounds

Answer (score 1):

There might be some incompatibilities between your `Keras` and `TensorFlow`. The thing that did the trick for me was uninstalling the `Keras` using `sudo pip uninstall keras` and re-installing it.