# Tensorflow 2.0 Error: ValueError: slice index 1 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for StridedSlice

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I am getting an error while compiling a tensorflow model. I am trying to concat a LSTM model create after vectorizing a column and feature layer for rest columns using tensorflow.feature_column.

While compiling I'm getting the below error:

```
Error: ValueError: slice index 1 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for '{{node model_7/text_vectorization_1/strided_slice}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1](model_7/text_vectorization_1/Shape, model_7/text_vectorization_1/strided_slice/stack, model_7/text_vectorization_1/strided_slice/stack_1, model_7/text_vectorization_1/strided_slice/stack_2)' with input shapes: [1], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <1>, input[2] = <2>, input[3] = <1>.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some similar issues [issue in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50385447/how-to-deal-with-keras-erroslice-index-0-of-dimension-0-out-of-bounds) and here on [github issues](https://github.com/JHart96/keras_elmo_embedding_layer/issues/1) Maybe you can provide all your code or at least the model.